# How to animate transformation of CGPath in SKShapeNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uibezierpath, skaction, cgpath

In my scene I use three basic shapenodes: squares, circles and triangles. I want to create a custom SKAction that animates the transformation from one shape kind to another.

I am trying to recreate something like [this](http://codepen.io/noahblon/blog/an-intro-to-svg-animation-with-smil) in SpriteKit.

I'm using UIBezierPath to generate the CGPath for each shape:

```
//Circles
UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect)

//Squares
UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect)

//Triangles
convenience init(triangleInRect:CGRect, centered:Bool) {
    self.init()
    var origin = CGPointZero
    if centered {
        origin = CGPoint(x: -triangleInRect.width / 2, y: -triangleInRect.height / 2)
    }
    moveToPoint(origin)
    addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: origin.x + triangleInRect.width, y: origin.y))
    addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: origin.x + triangleInRect.width / 2, y: origin.y + triangleInRect.height))
    closePath()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An animation sequence...

1. As shown in the diagram on the left of Figure 1, draw the top of a square by drawing a quadratic curve from points *P1* to *P2* with control point *CP*. With the control point on the line *P1P2*, the "curve" will be a line
2. Move points *P1* and *P2* by a small amount along the line from the corners of the square to the center, *C*
3. Update the control point, *CP*, such that its *y* position is above the square
4. Drawing the resulting quad curve from *P1* to *P2* with control point *CP* will produce the curve in the right of Figure 1. If the distance from the top of the square to the control point is the same as the distance from P1 (and P2) to the top of the square, the apex of the curve will be on the square
5. Repeat steps 2-4 for the other 3 sides of the square
6. Lather, rinse, repeat steps 2 - 5 until *P1* and *P2* are on the circle

and a drawing...

[image]

and a view clip...

[image]